# yamale schema to validate a self-referencing yaml file

Tags: validation, yaml

I'm looking to use yamale to validate a yaml file that contains the following type of structure:

```
MODEL_OPTIONS:
  MODEL_1: def_1
  MODEL_2: def_2
  MODEL_3: def_3

MODELS_TO_TRY: [MODEL_1, MODEL_3]
```

Namely, I want yamale to check that the only models listed in `MODELS_TO_TRY` are those defined in `MODEL_OPTIONS`. Reading through he yamale documentation and stackoverflow I haven't found what I'm looking for. Is this possible, and if so how?